# How would I redirect this?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have made a page where user can come and create a blog, an excerpt from **creating a new blog** page :-

```
<tr>
<td>Blog URL</td>
<td>www.foo.com/blogs/ <input type="text" name="ns"></td>
</tr>
```

Now, the user would enter something in that text box, suppose, the user enters **foobar**..then how can I make a setting a .htaccess so that the user can access that blog via **www.foo.com/blogs/foobar** instead of something www.foo.com/blogs.php?id=somethinghere ..

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks.

**Update**

Thanks @anubhava for that htaccess code, but it doesn't seems to be working correctly, here's what I have right now.

**blogs.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbconnector.php';
include 'functions.php';
$owner=$_SESSION['username'];
$id=$_GET['id'];

$equery="select * from events where eventid = '" . $id . "'";
$resulte=mysql_query($resulte) or die (mysql_error($db));
$rowe=mysql_fetch_assoc($resulte);
if((isset($_SESSION['logged'])) && ($_SESSION['logged']==1))
{
?>

Name : <?php echo ($rowe['name']); ?>
Zipcode : <?php echo ($rowe['zipcode']); ?>
<?php
}
else
{
    header('Location:/login/');
    exit();
}
?>
```

This code should've plucked up records for a blog with id something and then rewrite the url to www.foo.com/blogs/namehere if I directly open up www.foo.com/blogs/namehere

**namehere** is the name which the user has entered while creating a blog, but the only error I get is a 404 page not found.
Really confused here, please explain how this is going to work.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not instead just route all requests to /blogs/ to /blogs.php in your htaccess, passing the rest of the url as a querystring param? you won't need to modify it for each blog.

Comment: Shouldn't `$resulte=mysql_query($resulte)` be `$resulte=mysql_query($equery)` ? Or, is that a typo?

Comment: @Fred-ii- , that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /m/

RewriteRule ^blogs/(.+)$ blogs.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thankyou for the code @anubhava,
Here's another thing, how would I fetch all the details(from database) regarding that specific blog?.For example, www.foo.com/blogs/foobar

Comment: Just updated my previous question, could you please have a look?

Comment: Yes, that works..this is the URL :- http://localhost/m/blogs.php?id=4
(local wamp server)

Comment: Does `blogs.php` and `.htaccess` at the same level under DOCUMENT_ROOT OR they are in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/m/`?

Comment: Both **.htaccess** and **blogs.php** are under DOCUMENT_ROOT/m/

Comment: That worked. 
But, it doesn't displays the content. 
It displays :- Name : Zipcode : rather than displaying Name : somethinng Zipcode :something. 

I guess the records arent getting pulled?

Comment: Use `echo $_GET['id'];` to check. It should be there.

Comment: Added this line **echo "id = " . $id;** , a blank result.

Comment: Fixed it.
Thanks for the all the guidance @anubhava.